# Mac could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikit-image?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I tried `pip install scikit-image`, 
however, the output:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/*vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl*.py:315:
>   SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI
>   (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this
>   platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS
>   certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more
>   information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
>   SNIMissingWarning   Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-image/: There was a problem
>   confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>   certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598) - skipping  Could not find a
>   version that satisfies the requirement scikit-image (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for scikit-image

Any ideas? Thank you so much!

And then I was trying to solve the problem based on the information on the website It seems like I have problems to enable SSL on Google AppEngine.I don't know how could I do it and is it necessary in order to install certifi?

Comment: Have you read the error message? Someone actually made a real effort of writing a super-helpful error message with it's own online FAQ listing.

Comment: I read the post and tried to solve the problem follow the author's post, however, when I tried to install certifi the same problem happened which prevented me to go further. Do you have any other suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Please describe your research effort in the initial post. Tou can use the edit function to add details.

Answer (score 1):

do you try  `sudo pip install ****`  ?

Answer (score 0):

If **pip install scikit-image** does not work then use:
 **pip install --upgrade scikit-image**

It will first install **scikit-image** automatically then upgrade it.